# Why does a const reference to volatile int need a static_cast?

Tags: c++, volatile

Given the following code:

```
struct Foo { 
    volatile int i; 
};

const int& bar = foo.i;
```

I get:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const int&' from expression of type 'volatile int'
```

Unless I provide a `static_cast<volatile int>`.

Comment: Would you add an explanation on why you think it shouldn't need it?

Comment: @K-ballo Trying to compile code that isn't mine, and I came across other code that has static_cast and it works.

Comment: `volatile` is almost exactly like `const` when it comes to this stuff. The standard has the term *cv-qualified*, or even just *cv* in general, everywhere.

Comment: You're effectively asking to be able to access the `volatile int` `foo.i` using the name `bar`, where `bar` doesn't consider `foo.i` `volatile`: this is risky - it means updates to `bar` might not impact the memory for `foo.i` immediately, and if some hardware or whatever updates `foo.i`, future reads of `bar` might not see the changes.  Using an explicit cast is your option for saying "that's intended, let me do it".  This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410733/why-is-it-dangerous-to-get-rid-of-volatile?rq=1

Comment: I really hope you know what `volatile` means and why it's rarely a good idea to get rid of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Volatility" of types in C++ works in pretty much exactly the same way as "const-ness" -- that is, an object that is `volatile` cannot be assigned to a non-`volatile` reference, in just the same way that

```
const int i = 3;
int& j = i; // won't work
```

Similarly, only methods marked `volatile` can be called on a volatile object:

```
struct S
{
    void do_something() volatile {}
    void do_something_else() {}
};

volatile S s;
s.do_something(); // fine
s.do_something_else(); // won't work
```

Methods can be overloaded by "volatility", in the same way they can be overloaded by const-ness.

In C++ standardese, these things are known as *cv-qualifiers*, to emphasise that they work in exactly the same way. (C99 adds a third that works in the same way, `restrict`, available as an extension in some C++ compilers). You can change *cv* qualifiers using `const_cast<>` -- the more powerful `static_cast<>` isn't required.

EDIT:

Just to make clear, a type can have both `const` and `volatile` modifiers at the same time, giving a total of four possibilities:

```
int i;
const int j;
volatile int k;
const volatile int l;
```

Answer (score 3):

As with `const`, a `volatile` object can only be referred to by a `volatile` reference. Otherwise, the compiler has no way of knowing that accesses to the object via the reference need to be volatile.

```
volatile const int& bar = foo.i;
^^^^^^^^
```

> Unless I provide a `static_cast<volatile int>`

It's rarely a good idea to silence a compiler error by adding casts. This doesn't give you a reference to `foo.i`, but to a separate copy of it.

If you are doing something really strange that requires a non-volatile reference to a volatile object, you'd need `const_cast` to remove the qualifer:

```
const int& weird = const_cast<int&>(foo.i);
```